# Avplayer and wkwebview video play

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, wkwebview

I want play video in AVPlayer and WKWebView simultaneously. 
For now when video in WKWebView starts AVPlayer get stops.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to play two videos simultaneously than use two AVPlayer to play each video.

Comment: Did not answer question